# BurnTotalSupply

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

If all tokens are distributed and no one is burning their own tokens then how can a function like below burn from total supply? can a function like this really burn other peoples tokens?

```
function burnTotalSupply(uint256 tokenAmount) external onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
        require(tokenAmount > 0);
        require(totalSupply.sub(tokenAmount) > 0);

        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(tokenAmount);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(tokenAmount.div(10 ** uint256(decimals)));

        return totalSupply;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can a function like this really burn other peoples tokens?

No. The function will burn a certain amount of any remaining tokens, presumably which weren't, or haven't yet been, sold in the crowdsale or distribution phase. By changing the supply like this they can change the scarcity of, and therefore (they hope) demand for, the remaining tokens.

Comment: They happened to have one for increasing total supply as well, why would anyone want to implement this? but those functions would only be able to impact amount sold during the crowdsale and not the supply after the crowdsale right **the functions are implemented in the token contract not the crowdsale contract but the crowdsale contract inherits the token contract**

Comment: Again, for the same reason. If you control supply (decrease _or_ increase), you can control the scarcity of the token, and therefore control the price. If the crowdsale contract inherits the token contract, then it also inherits those functions, meaning they can control the supply both during the crowdsale and afterwards (by the sound of it).

Comment: what if there is no tokens remaining and this is called from the token contract? would the burning be distributed across the total amount of token owners and then take the average amount of tokens so everyone lose the same amount? or would it simply fail